# Force Rake Task To Run in Specific Rails Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I need to run a series of Rake tasks from another Rake task. The first three tasks need to be run in the development environment, but the final task needs to be run in the staging environment. The task has a dependency on `:environment` which causes the Rails development environment to be loaded before the tasks run.

However, I need the final task to be executed in the staging environment.

Passing a `RAILS_ENV=staging` flag before invoking the rake task is no good as the environment has already loaded at this point and all this will do is set the flag, not load the staging environment.

**Is there a way I can force a rake task in a specific environment?**

Comment: You probably can't, because environment settings are global. You can do it through a separate system call, such as `system({RAILS_ENV: 'staging'}, "rake staging_command")`.

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov I'm actually using `system`, but it doesn't reload the environment.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reload the environment'? It does reload the Ruby interpreter along with the entire application. What else should be reloaded?

Comment: I mean that a new instance of the Rails app isn't loaded before the rake task runs. I can clearly see this by logging from `application.rb` which is not loaded a second time.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct log for the staging environment?

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov Yep. Something strange going on though. Tried with some vanilla rake tasks and the environment is reloaded, but with `rake assets:precompile` which is the task I need to run in `staging` the environment isn't reloaded.

Answer (score 21):

I've accomplished this kind of this before, albeit not in the most elegant of ways:

```
task :prepare do
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=development")      
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=development")
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=test")
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=test")
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=test")
  system("bundle exec rake ... RAILS_ENV=test")
end
```

It's always worked for me. I'd be curious to know if there was a better way.

Comment: I couldn't use Matt Schwartz's solution above because I'm stuck on Ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2.2.2.   This solution worked pretty well, actually.  Ugly but simple.  Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

The way I solved it was to add a dependency to set the rails env before the task is invoked:

```
namespace :foo do
  desc "Our custom rake task"
  task :bar => ["db:test:set_test_env", :environment] do
      puts "Custom rake task"
      # Do whatever here...
      puts Rails.env
  end
end


namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    desc "Custom dependency to set test environment"
    task :set_test_env do # Note that we don't load the :environment task dependency
      Rails.env = "test"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi there how can i call task :set_test_env from controller?

Comment: In Rails 4, that won't work. The main config is loaded from Rakefile, before the task is defined let alone run.